# How to get a portion of a string

Tags: c++, c, string

How to get a portion of a string.

For Example, the string is:

> > Input String: "53 56 4B 00 00 41 41 2F 41 54 43 43 54 52 31 2E 41 54 31 2E 4E 37 38"
> >
> > ```
> >                |                                        |
> >               ptr1                                     ptr2
> > ```

`ptr1` It's always going to be at the 7th position starting from left to right

`ptr2` It's always going to be at the 13th position starting from right to left

Output string:

```
4B 00 00 41 41 2F 41 54 43 43 54 52 31 2E 41 54 31
```

Comment: You tagged it C; is using `std::string` ok?

Comment: yes...everything would be fine....no matter its char*  or string

Comment: @VikasChhipa If it's C it makes a difference. You wouldn't have to go through all the work in C++ using a string. Which is it?

Comment: @Octopusgrabbus, okay sir, then consider it in C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C:

```
char substr[MAX_LEN + 1];

strncpy(substr, input + 6, MAX_LEN);
substr[strlen(substr) - 12] = '\0';
```

In C++:

```
substr = input.substr(6, input.size() - (6 + 12));
```

This does no error handling on the input string.

Answer (score 5):

If you already have the pointers, this is very simple. Use the [`std::string` constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) that takes a pointer and a length.

```
std::string result(ptr1, ptr2 - ptr1);
```

Or as pointed out in the comments, since pointers can also be used as iterators you can use the dual iterator constructor:

```
std::string result(ptr1, ptr2);
```

Comment: You could change `ptr2 - ptr1` to simply `ptr2` and you'd be using the iterator version, which is much more appealing to my C++ sensibilities.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, why didn't I think of that? I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `std::string`, you can use the [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::string.substr` function. It is desingned for this purpose.

It takes two aguments: the first is the index from where to begin "extract", and the second is the count of "extracted" chars.

Example:

```
string hello = "Hello World";
string part = hello.substr(6, hello.size() - 6); // part == "World"
```

So, if you have two indeces `i` and `j`, where i <= j, a substring from `i` to `j`, inclusive would be found by

```
string part = original.substr(i, j - i + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, without modifying the input string:

```
char *ptr1,*ptr2;
if(strlen(instring)<13) { /** error; not long enough **/ }
ptr1 = instring+7;
ptr2 = instring+strlen(instring)-13;
```

The pointers here just point to a position in the input string.  If you need to modify it without modifying the original input string, use `strncpy`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your ptr1 and ptr2 backwards or left/right mixed up. But what I would do to get the X position from the right is iterate from the last element of the string until I hit the Xth position, then calculate how far X is from the left, then use string.substr().

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/